# Initializing a non-const static string with a constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17

Is the following code correct?

```
constexpr char s[] = "a, bb, ccc";
static const char * s1 = s;
char * s2 = const_cast<char *>(s1);
s2[5] = 'x';
```

my first idea was that 's' exists only at compile time and 's1' probably is some kind of a copy of 's', but probably it is not quite correct because line 2 does not compile without 'const':

```
static char * s1 = s;
```

The error with MSCV2017 is: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [11]' to 'char [11]'.

so it is not clear what is the relation between 's' and 's1'? Do they reference the same string literal?

Comment: Note that [the `c++17` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) is for the C++17 *standard*, not about MSVC2017 (that would be the `visual-studio-2017` tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition

```
static const char * s1 = s;
```

is equal to

```
static const char * s1 = &s[0];
```

That is, you make `s1` point to the first element of `s`, that's all. There's no "copy" being made.

That's why you can't use pointers to non-const (i.e. `char *`) since `s1` will point to constant data.

And that's also why `s2[5] = 'x'` will lead to *undefined behavior* as you attempt to modify constant data.

Comment: does this code lead to undefined behavior: {const int a = 1; const_cast<int *>(&a) = 5;} ?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky It does not even compile `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: @Tetix OP missed a dereference or OP could have used a reference directly, but the point is that you cannot modify `a`.

Comment: @Tetix I meen {const int a = 1; *(const_cast<int *>(&a)) = 5;}

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Yes that's UB. Any attempt to modify constant data leads to UB.

Comment: @Acorn what is const_cast for?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what is const_cast for?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Any use of `const_cast` should be a red flag that there's something bad going on. As would old C-style casts.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky You can't cast away `const` using other C++ casting primitives, only using [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast). But as I said above, don't do it.

Comment: @alexey if you have a pointer to const or reference to const, *and* you know the data actually isn't const, const cast lets you safely cast it away.  If you are wrong, it is UB.  You can also add const with const cast.

Answer (score 1):

> my first idea was that 's' exists only at compile time

No, it also exists at run-time. `constexpr` does not mean "only at compile-time". What it means here is "`s` must be initialized with a constant expression" (a compile-time constant, basically), which means itself can be used in constant expressions, too.

> 's1' probably is some kind of a copy of 's'

`s1` simply points to the first character of the `s` array. It is not a copy of the contents of the array.

> line 2 does not compile without 'const':

You can't do that without `const_cast` -- but you wouldn't want anyway, because it is undefined behavior to modify a originally-`const` variable (which `s` is).